# How to select an ActiveX Option/Radio Buttons in Form Controls

Tags: vba, excel, activex

I have a Form Control with ActiveX Radio/Option Buttons in it.
The Form Control name is Side and contains Option/Radio Buttons with names xOption, oOption, and randomSide.
How would I be able to create a Macro that would allow me to set the radio buttons to a certain value upon opening the workBook. Recording a Macro of me clicking options results in a blank Macro. I've Already tried:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Side")).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("xOption").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1
```

But this gives me error 1004 and other codes give me error 91. I'm really new to VBA so if I look stupid you know why.

Comment: do you want one option selected when you open the workbook?

Comment: @paulinhax Yea, just one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, using `Worksheets` instead of `ActiveSheet`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
    Worksheets("your sheet name here").OLEObjects("xOption").Object.Value = 1 
End Sub
```

As you want it to be selected after opening the sheet. Place this on `ThisWorkbook`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this...

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("xOption").Object.Value = 1
```

Comment: This gave me a 1004 error, unable to get the OLEObjects Propert of the worksheet Class

Comment: Since the code will work on ActiveSheet, are you sure that there is an ActiveX Option Button on the ActiveSheet? Also make sure that the name of the option button is as same as used in the code.